# Ajax jQuery Not passing Variable to Data Undefined Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading data using a page scroll function. When I hard code the data line in my function everything works ok

For example this works sortby is set to "asc"

```
data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: "asc" }',
```

This doesn't work and I get undefined message

```
data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: '+ sortby +' }',
```

I have set an alert in the function and the value of var sortby does equal asc the alert box pops up when I scroll to the bottom of the page which is correct.

But it's not getting passed and causing the undefined error

This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pageIndex = 1;
  var pageCount;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        GetRecords();
    }
  });
  function getdropdownlistSelectedItem(sender, args) {
    var raddropdownlist = $find('<%=RadDropDownList1.ClientID %>');
    var selecteditem = raddropdownlist.get_selectedItem().get_value() || "asc";
    return selecteditem;
  }
  function GetRecords() {
    var sortby = getdropdownlistSelectedItem();
    alert('Sortby: ' + sortby);
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
      $("#loader").show();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "categorypage.aspx/GetCustomers",
        // data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: "asc" }',
        data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: '+ sortby +' }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
          alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
          alert(response.d);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone please show me how to pass this value correctly?

Thanks.

[image: Alert box shows correct value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're not wrapping the string contained in `sortby` in quotes. Try this:

```
data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + ', sortby: "'+ sortby +'" }',
```

Note the double quotes around the second concatenated value.

Better still would be to not build an ugly concatenated string yourself, but instead just provide an object to the `data` property. jQuery will encode it as required for you:

```
data: {
  pageIndex: pageIndex,
  sortby: sortby
},
```

Comment: thanks wrapping it worked. when I tried the other part I got undefined again